# Liftweb and memory in hosting? Tune up liftweb?

Tags: scala, hosting, lift

I want to deploy web application developed using [liftweb](http://liftweb.net) framework, I looked for good hosting and decided to use webfaction.com, they have pretty good features, but have very strict in memory.

If web application is just catalog, that don't have some heavy stuff in server side, and only getting all from Mysql and rendering pages, 
how much memory I need?

How to tune up liftweb applications?

I have already see some links from David Pollak about tuning up, but links was broken, can any body give working link?

What is best choice to test web application for memory?

And does any one have experienced webfaction, because as I chatted tech support I must install apache tomcat from sources, can you give some advise how to do it in a best way?

Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using Lift with Tomcat and MySQL on VPS box, and as I can see after some months my application usually requires about 80Mb of RAM. Under testing load (50 visitors simultaneously) RAM usage was about 130-150Mb (CPU utilization was about 10-20%, but I have no heavy SQL queries). This is for 32-bit host system, under 64-bit host RAM usage will be increased.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Amazon EC2, you can even get away for free using micro isntanctes.
http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/